# Rigify grabbing geometry like it's a leopard print

Tags: animation, objects, rigify

[image]I created a model, followed tutorials on how to set the meta rig, got it parented to the geometry with auto-weight, go to move a finger to test and the model turns into a porcupine. I look under weight painting and it does this. I've wiped out a few vertex groups and repainted, but it keeps resetting to be scattered across the whole body rather than isolated to the geometry I want the bone to move. I can't find why its doing this, I don't even know what to call it to search for a solution. In the attached picture, the vertex group selected is the left breast after repainting to 0 and then painting where I wanted it. I went back into object mode, returned to weight painting and it had automatically rescattered itself across the body. IDKWTF I'm doing wrong here but this is NOT logical behavior from the software. There is NO reason it should be doing this

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Gonna take 8+hours before I can. Left for work

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the rig is grabbing geometry it THINKS is in that location, but the geometry isn't really in that location. idk how Blender would mistake where an object is in the scene but still display it properly. I'm hoping someone has potentially seen this error before

Comment: It will also probably help to mention the model was created by using boolean modifiers to take geometry from other models and combine them together. I don't believe that should matter, but you never know

Comment: Did you apply all of the Booleans before parenting?  If so, it might be this: The automatic weight algorithm needs what is known as a "water tight" or "manifold" mesh model.  It looks like you've somehow managed to model your way into a model that has two or more such mesh models intertwined.  To tell if this is so, take the model in edit mode, deselect everything, hover over a vertex and type L.  It should select every vertex in the model.  If it doesn't that's your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole model was selected in that method. It seems it's watertight. I've even gone so far as to start over from scratch and try it again to see if I was still getting incorrect automatic weighting (before posting here) and that didn't solve the issue either. This has been a 2 day head scratcher and definitely one that makes me want to give up on all computers and go live with the Amish

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a file would be great. But it looks like a messy mesh.

Try this: In edit mode select all geometry and

- click Mesh menu > Merge > Merge by distance
- press Shift+N (recalculate normals)

Then try to parent with automatic weights again.
I'll edit my answer if you share a file.